# Parsing MS Excel file for a user listing from a concatenated field

Tags: vba, excel, parsing

I have attached an image of the excel file that a client provided (names have been changed to protect the innocent).  I need to take the information from the *Users in group* column and create a normalized table.  At the bottom of the image I've shown an example of the table I am looking to create.

Here is an example of the text in the *Users in Group* column to copy for testing. The " , " always separates distinct users.

cn:Donavan Keairnes uid:dkea employeeNumber:18669 , cn:Eric Ly uid:ely employeeNumber:12479 ,

[image: Image of MS Excel file]

I am pretty good with Excel, but I have done very little VBA scripting.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see?  a list of names in a new sheet?

Comment: Yes, a listing of the users in that group in a new sheet or workbook

Comment: Any chance you'd consider Access instead?

Comment: Well, let me clarify that the new sheet would contain the user listing for all groups.

Comment: Excel + VBA are good for 1 dimensional input and output (formulas), but once you need variable numbers of rows, you have to start emulating tables with VBA. Access has them natively.

Comment: Yea, MS Access or MS SQL Server is fine.  I prefer to use MS SQL instead of Access

Comment: If the data was a little more structured - like quotes around the fields `key:"value"` and a special character separating them, you might be able to get away with `Split`. As it is, you almost have to do straight parsing, but I think you can get away with using just regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to just give you code - if you're just looking for code that will solve the problem, you can try one of the many freelance sites. Here are the ingredients you need to solve it yourself!

First, use the VBA `Split` function to separate users. The function takes a string and a delimiter. For example, `Split("cn:Donavan Keairnes uid:dkea employeeNumber:18669 , cn:Eric Ly uid:ely employeeNumber:12479 ,", ",")` yields an array with three elements: `["cn:Donavan Keairnes uid:dkea employeeNumber:18669 ", " cn:Eric Ly uid:ely employeeNumber:12479 ", ""]`, and you can ignore the last one since it will always be blank.

Next, you can use a Regular Expression to capture the individual fields as matches: `(\w+:(\w+(\s+|$))+)` ([here's an example of how this works](https://regex101.com/r/Yj1Dep/1)).

Finally, you can capture the `key:value` pairs by using `Split` again with a delimiter of ":" for each match. If need be, you can use the VBA function `Trim`, which takes a single string argument and returns that string with leading and trailing spaces removed, to clean up the values.

Once you have your final results collected together, you can plug them back into the spreadsheet!